# Finding the Matrix of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a problem finding the matrix of a linear transformation for:

> $T(x_1 + x_2)= x_1, T(x_1 - x_2) = x_2$

I tried to solve this by representing the first transformation as:

\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d \end{pmatrix}

and multiplying by the coefficients of the first transformation, s.t the resulting matrix is

\begin{pmatrix} 
a + b \\
c + d \end{pmatrix}

which is equal to:

\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
0 \end{pmatrix}

repeating the same process for the second transformation, I obtained the following system of equations:

\begin{array}{lcl} a  +b  = 1, a - b = 0 \\ c + d = 0, c-d=1 \end{array}

to which I get:

\begin{pmatrix} 
.5 + .5 \\
.5 - .5 \end{pmatrix}

Is this correct?

Comment: Compute $T(x_1)$ and $T(x_2)$ using linearity. These values will be your columns.

Comment: A linear transformation makes no sense unless you specify the domain $V$ and the codomain $W$.  The matrix of the transformation makes no sense unless you also specify a basis for $V$ and a basis for $W$.  If you supply these details then perhaps someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @David I assumed $x_1$ and $x_2$ were a basis for both spaces. Can't see any other possibility! xD